# No query results for model ? But why?

Tags: php, laravel, model

like in the headline is written, I'm getting a :

```
No query results for model [App\Models\Thread\Comment].
```

Error message. I'm getting this error after I'm trying to delete a Thread. The funny thing is that this Error Message says "No results for the Comment Model. But I wan't to delete a thread, not a comment. It doesn't matter if the Thread have some comments or not, I'm getting this error message every time I try it. I can't really say why, cause I haven't changed the Comment Model. Can someone have a look over it?

My Comment model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Thread;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public $table = 'comments';
    public $fillable = [
        'comment',
        'thread_id',
        'user_id',
    ];

    public function commentuser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Thread Model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Thread;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thread extends Model
{
    public $table = 'thread';
    public $fillable = [
        'thread',
        'content',
        'user_id',
        'themen_id',
    ];

    public function userthread()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function threadthema()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Thread\Thema', 'thema_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

The delete route:

```
Route::delete('/show/{id}', ['as' => 'destroycomment', 'uses' => 'Test\\TestController@destroycomment']);
```

The blade where the threads + the comments are:

http://pastebin.com/0NUPx18C

distroy method in controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);
    $thread->delete();
    return redirect(action('Test\\TestController@startpage', [Auth::user()->id]));
}
```

Comment: Edit: The model is okay, I tried to get my comments on another blade and got them all, so my model should be okay.. I also uncomment  all the lines where a I'm getting something from my Comment Model but the Error is still there

Comment: You probably should how us what's happening at the `destroycomment` method on your controller.

Comment: That's strange.  Somewhere you must be aliasing your `Comment` model to `Thread`.  If you do `Thread::class`, does that return `App\Models\Thread\Comment`?  In the controller you aren't doing something like `use App\Models\Thread\Comment as Thread;` are you?

Comment: Another thought, if you are trying to alias these classes, you may also want to check that your `aliases` array in `config/app.php` is correct.